# Get the address of the array element in a structure

Tags: c

How do we get the address of the array element through structure pointer ?

I have an example code as follows :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct {
    int mynam ;
 } transrules;

typedef struct {
    int ip ;
    int udp;
    transrules rules[256];

}__attribute__ ((__packed__)) myudp;

myudp  udpdata ;
myudp* ptrudp = &udpdata ;

int main(){

    memset (&udpdata , 0 ,sizeof(udpdata));
    ptrudp->ip = 12 ;
    ptrudp->udp = 13 ;
    ptrudp->rules[0].mynam = 15 ;
    printf("%d",ptrudp->rules[0].mynam);
    return 0;

}
```

My function wants the address of the rules[0] to be passed as an argument .Is it possible to print the address of the rule[0] or as a matter of fact any i.e rule[n] ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to print the address of the rule[0] or as a matter of
>   fact any i.e rule[n]

Yes, it's possible:

```
printf("%p\n", (void *) &ptrudp->rules[i]); /* Cast required by %p. */
```

The same way you can pass a pointer to `rules[i]` to your function.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to structure points to a *structure*, so the adress of an element still available.

```
f(&ptrudp->rules[n]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You access it as you would normally do with any other array, just grab it from the structure using the `->` operator:

```
transrules *addr = &ptrudp->rules[n];
```